# Google Cloud Run OAuth2 Authentication with PKCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I need to authenticate a service account (with container invoke role) in Cloud Run with PKCE.
Basically my iOS app sends HTTPS requests to invoke certain Cloud Run Container (with Django Rest Framework).

I found this [example](https://github.com/stephendarling/cloud-run-flask-oauth2/tree/ac2ae76c492e679a52e638c7b1f79041f3c20510) (which authenticates to the Cloud Run endpoint via self-signed JWT in exchange for token). This is exactly what I need, but I want to add PKCE. I'm confused as to where do I send code_verifier and code_challenge? If I do the verification in my container, how would that link to Cloud Run authorization.

Comment: You want to connect directly your iOS app to Cloud Run? If so, do you want to use user authentication for doing this? If so, do your users have a google account?

Comment: I don't want to use user authentication. I just want to make sure the request is sent only from iOS app. I have created only one service account with 'invoke' permissions, I need to securely authenticate that account form iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (bad) solution is to generate a service account key file and to embed it in your iOS app; But, as mentioned by John, if you do this, you lost the control of your key because your mobile isn't safe. Instead of doing this, make your service public!!

The good pattern is to not let your user directly call your private and secure service, but to have a public gateway that perform the user security check. Thereby, you will use the OAuth flow of your user to authenticate it on a backend, and this backend will be able to call your service, with the right service account.

You can do it by yourself, but the good alternative is to use an API Gateway, like Cloud Endpoint on GCP. You can plug firebase authentication on it. Your overhead is minimal, and your security improved! I [wrote and article in relation with this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) (it's about API Keys, but replace the API Key security definition by [the firebase auth security definition](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase), and enjoy!)

Comment: I'm trying to implement your approach. So far I've set up Cloud Endpoint which works fine. I'm having trouble adding Firebase Authentication. I followed this (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) to setup  authentication definition in OpenAPI file. This (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request) however suggests that signed JWT should be generated on the client side. Does this mean I have to keep service account credentials on the client side? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your first link is the correct one. However, your Cloud Endpoint service (Cloud Run in my case) has to be deployed with a service account having the right authorization for calling your Functions or Cloud Run services defined in the OpenApi spec.

Comment: Yes, my Cloud Endpoint is deployed in public Cloud Run container with a service account which has 'invoke' authorization to call my other private Cloud Run container. I also defined security definition in OpenAPI file. How do I use Firebase Authentication now? The first link doesn't describe how to send authenticated requests. Do I use this ~Auth.auth().currentUser.getIDToken~?

Comment: Yes, you have to provide an ID token and not an access token.

Comment: I'm sending the ID token, can't get past this error: Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"

Comment: Where do you have this error? In the log of which service?

Comment: So, I tried both in Postman and Curl (I run the app, print the token and then use it) , and from the app directly. Postman, Curl, and Cloud Run Endpoint Logs show 403

Comment: Turns out the issue is not authentication, it works fine. The problem is with POST requests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163299/problem-with-django-post-request-in-google-cloud-endpoint

Comment: Good to know!! Thanks for your feedback!!

Answer (score 1):

Google OAuth does not implement PKCE.

PKCE is part of the Authorization Code Flow. Service accounts do not use this Flow.

Authorization Code Flow is not part of Google service account authorization, as both sides are considered trusted. A mobile device is not a trusted device, therefore do NOT store service accounts on mobile devices.

Comment: I was trying to follow this (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/understanding-oauth2-and-deploy-a-basic-auth-srv-to-cloud-functions) tutorial which included PKCE. If Authorization Code Flow is not part of service account authorization, how can I authorize a service account from iOS app? I want to make sure that Google Cloud Run container is invoked only if if request comes from iOS app.

Comment: The tutorial mentions PKCE. Google does not implement PKCE. Use Google Accounts via OAuth and not a service account.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't need to authenticate my users' Google Accounts. I'm not accessing their email addresses or any other data. All I'm accessing is my own Cloud Run Container.

If you look at this tutorial https://medium.com/@stephen.darling/oauth2-authentication-with-google-cloud-run-700015a092c2 the author is using authorized service account to access his own Cloud Run Container. 

I don't want my Cloud Run request URL to be accessible by anyone but me. If I authorize user Google Accounts, then anyone with Google Account can access it.

Comment: @mezzi Only those member accounts that you authorize can access Cloud Run unless you authorize everyone. Your assumption is wrong. Just using a service account does not grant access to Cloud Run. You must authorize that identity also.