# Securing cloud run http end point for firebase android client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

We have deployed a flask api running Google Cloud Run and have a RESTful HTTP endpoint. We intend this to be called by our iOS app which integrates with firebase (we want writes to go through a REST request instead directly to collection, for business logic).

Is there way that we can make it secure/leverage gcloud authentication capabilities?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users

Comment: Similar to this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040860/google-cloud-run-oauth2-authentication-with-pkce/61048370#61048370